# number format to char in oracle while creating a view

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below view:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE  VIEW viewA ("col1", "col2") AS 
  SELECT DISTINCT CAST("col1" AS CHAR(1)),
 CAST(to_char("col2",'00.0000') AS char(7))
  FROM tableA
```

the col2 has data like 22.33 or 2.3 or 0.2345 or 2 but, four digits in dec and 2 digits in number.
It has to be written into a file with fixed length of 7 digits including decimal. Hence i wrote col2, '00.0000', but the number format'23.234' is written into col2 as 23.234 without any trailing zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format code of `00.0000` should include the fourth decimal place for `23.234`; it's always worked for me. I'm using Oracle 11.

The problem I got when I tried doing `CAST(TO_CHAR(23.234, '00.0000') AS CHAR(7))` was the error `ORA-25137: Data value out of range`. This happens because because the `TO_CHAR` returns a string of length 8:

```
SQL> SELECT '[' || TO_CHAR(23.234, '00.0000') || ']' FROM DUAL

'['||TO_CH
----------
[ 23.2340]
```

`TO_CHAR` leaves a space at the beginning in case the number is negative, in which case it will put a minus sign there. You can get rid of the leading space by using the `FM` modifier in the format string:

```
SQL> SELECT '[' || TO_CHAR(23.234, 'FM00.0000') || ']' FROM DUAL

'['||TO_CH
----------
[23.2340]
```

This is all a long way of saying "try this instead" - the only change is the `FM` in the `TO_CHAR` format string:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewA ("col1", "col2") AS 
SELECT DISTINCT
  CAST("col1" AS CHAR(1)),
  CAST(to_char("col2",'FM00.0000') AS char(7))
FROM tableA
```

One final note: enclosing the column names with double quotes makes them case sensitive, and that often leads to trouble. I'd recommend losing the double quotes if you can.

Comment: i changed it to to_char("col2", '00.0000S') and it worked. I will remove the double quotes hence forth, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `RPAD` function that would add trailing zeros for you

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  VIEW viewA ("col1", "col2") AS 
SELECT DISTINCT CAST("col1" AS CHAR(1)),
   RPAD(CAST(to_char("col2",'00.0000') AS char(7)),7,'0')
 FROM tableA
```

But you might face a problem if your number did not have a decimal value, for example assuming the value is **12** you will end up with **1200000** but maybe this would give you an idea